# How to read which host of a MongoDB cluster answered my query (in Rust)?

Tags: mongodb, rust

I use MongoDB in a Rust application. I would like to know which server in the cluster send the response of a query.

I can see the information (`serverHost=`) when I [consume events](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-rust-driver/manual/tracing.html#consuming-events-with-tracing) with `tracing` crate but I would like to use it in my application and don't know how to access it.

I think, what I need is [ServerInfo.address](https://docs.rs/mongodb/2.7.0/mongodb/struct.ServerInfo.html#method.address) but it is not accessible from my Client instance.

**EDIT**: The code below is the minimum of what I am trying to do. How can the hostname of the responding server be assigned to `address` variable?

```
use mongodb::{bson::doc, options::{ClientOptions, ServerApi, ServerApiVersion}, Client};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> mongodb::error::Result<()> {
    // Replace the placeholder with your MongoDB connection string
    let uri = "<connection string>";
    let mut client_options = ClientOptions::parse(uri).await?;
    let client = Client::with_options(client_options)?;
    
    // Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
    client
        .database("admin")
        .run_command(doc! {"ping": 1}, None)
        .await?;
    
    // Somehow get hostname of responding server
    // let address = ...? 

    println!("Got ping from {}", address);

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a [`CommandEventHandler`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/mongodb/event/command/trait.CommandEventHandler.html) to use when building your `Client`. It will receive callbacks whenever commands are started, succeeded, or failed. Each of the callback payloads includes the [`ConnectionInfo`](https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/mongodb/event/command/struct.ConnectionInfo.html) that has the MongoDB server address.

If you're just aggregating metrics then this is probably all you need. But if you actually need the *caller* of the update or query to know what address was used, it gets a bit trickier. I would recommend using a [task-local](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.LocalKey.html) (if using the async `Client`) or a [thread-local](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.LocalKey.html) (if using the sync `Client`) that the event handler can store the address into from which the caller can extract.

Here's what I got working using task-locals:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, OnceLock};

use mongodb::bson::doc;
use mongodb::event::command::{CommandEventHandler, CommandSucceededEvent};
use mongodb::options::{ClientOptions, ServerAddress};
use mongodb::Client;
use tokio::task_local;

task_local! {
    static SERVER_ADDRESS: OnceLock<ServerAddress>;
}

struct ServerAddressHandler;

impl CommandEventHandler for ServerAddressHandler {
    fn handle_command_succeeded_event(&self, event: CommandSucceededEvent) {
        let _ = SERVER_ADDRESS.with(|address| address.set(event.connection.address));
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> mongodb::error::Result<()> {
    let uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

    let mut client_options = ClientOptions::parse(uri).await?;
    client_options.command_event_handler = Some(Arc::new(ServerAddressHandler));
    let client = Client::with_options(client_options)?;

    SERVER_ADDRESS
        .scope(OnceLock::new(), async {
            let result = client
                .database("admin")
                .run_command(doc! {"ping": 1}, None)
                .await;

            let address = SERVER_ADDRESS.with(|address| address.get().cloned());
            if let Some(address) = address {
                println!("Got ping from {address}");
            }

            result
        })
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

```
Got ping from localhost:27017
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, `CommandEventHandler` and Tokio's `task_local` look promising but I failed to get it work. I have provided a minimal example of what I am trying to do in the original post. Would it be the right approach?

Comment: @user22299554 I've updated my answer with code based on the code you provided.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much, @kmdreko! I misunderstood the usage and syntax of the task_local part but your code works perfectly and shows me what I need.